# list of all platforms in blockchain apart from Ethereum, Hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum

I am new in blockchain world. So far i could found 2 platforms: Ethereum, Hyperledger. Where to find list of more platforms, if any? Bitcoin is just a currency not a platform?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to Stackoverflow. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com is more suited for this type of question.

Comment: No, bitcoin.stackexchange.com is not more suited.
Bitcoin is a specific implementation of public blockchain.
Ethereum is another implementaiton of a public blockchain.
Hyperledger is a consortium of multiple private (permissioned blockchains).

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin is both a currency and a platform. You can take the bitcoin code (public domain) and create your own digital currency.

Ethereum is also both a currency and platform. It is more generalized than Bitcoin and allows running of applications.

Hyperledger is a consortium, that contains multiple blockchain implementations, such as Hyperledger Sawtooth, Hyperledger Fabric, Hyperledger Burrow, Hyperledger Indy, or Hyperledger Iroha.